# deploying xs module on CPAN

Tags: perl, xs

i was looking on different xs cpan modules and they didn't contains the actucal source code of the library they are binding ,

for example on this library https://st.aticpan.org/source/NANIS/Net-Sharktools-0.009/  the xs module :https://st.aticpan.org/source/NANIS/Net-Sharktools-0.009/Sharktools.xs

has "#include "sharktools_core.h" but if i browse the files on metacpan i didn't find this file .

the same issue with this module : https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA 
the .xs file contains #include to different openssl files but the files aren't on the distribution.

when such xs module installed how it include the header and compile the C files if they arn't part of the distribution?

Comment: Have a look at [`Devel::CheckLib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::CheckLib), a useful module to build XS code with external libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These distributions expect the libraries to be available on the system they are installing to. So for example for Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA it expects you to have `openssl-dev` or the equivalent package installed for your system. An option for making a distribution that doesn't require this is to (separately) release an [Alien](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien) distribution, and the easiest way to do this now is with [Alien::Build](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::Build). An Alien distribution represents either using the existing installed library or installing the library within Perl's library directories, either way it is made available for Perl to use. For example both [Alien::OpenSSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::OpenSSL) and [Alien::LibreSSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::LibreSSL) exist and can be used by distributions that want to make sure a SSL library is available. Your XS distribution would add the Alien distribution as a dependency and then can use the library via that.